# split character varying in old SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

i have a problem with splitting a String on a database cell, i got an old SQL version and I cannot use the SPLIT_STRING() function that would solve my problem.
I found that there is another function that seems to do the same job ( regexp_split_to_array ) but i don't understand the expression i need to use for splitting the string as i want.

E.G.: i have a character varying string like this

```
040078192-1.25;038250054-1.44     // variable number of segment like "040078192-1.25;"
```

and I need to split it two times, the first by the semicolon ';',  the second  by the '-'. so
what would it be the expression in

> regexp_split_to_array('040078192-1.25;038250054-1.44', {exp?})

to make it work?

also if you know any other way to solve the problem compatibile with older version of sql I am all ears.

edit: i'm using pgadmin3 with plain sql. What i want to obtain is an array like
{040078192-1.25, 038250054-1.44, 038143254-1.84, ...  }
then i want to do the same work on the array but using the '-' as divider and obtain something like: {{040078192, 1,25}, { 038250054,1.44} , ...}

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want. Please tag your questions with the database you are really using.  It does not appear to be SQL Server (as I originally thought).

Comment: Combination of `charindex` and `substring` should do the trick

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Postgres or a Postgres-compatible database, then you want:

```
select regexp_split_to_array('040078192-1.25;038250054-1.44', '[-;]')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4f918d30f9529f5cb9793cfc6faa5975) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I am using a postgres database but this gave me a syntax error on the  '[;]'

Comment: @MarianoMariani . . . The db<>fiddle has a working example.